# How to configure Powermta with PHP?

Tags: php, powermta

Is it possible to configure powermta with php to send emails, I did searched on google and not found any good resource.

If anybody did it please post some ideas or code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can connect  PowerMTA with php, use this php class

```
 https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
```

you just need to provide smtp hostname with smtp port and user credentials to connect to PowerMTA.

Comment: This answer is not right. First give us code example.